# Eigen values and vectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$$ X'(t)= \begin{bmatrix}x'(t)\\ y'(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-5 & -2\\-1 & -4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

Sketch the directions field for the system, plot the straight line solutions
for each Eigenvalue, specify the corresponding straight line solution and its x(t) and y(t).

I found the Eigenvalues which are $-6, -3$ and the vectors $v_1 = (2,1) , v_2 = (-1,1)$

I need help to plot the lines

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- You found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors correctly.
- The solution is given as:

$$x(t) =  \dfrac{1}{3} c_1 e^{-6 t} (e^{3 t}+2)- \dfrac{2}{3} c_2 e^{-6 t} (e^{3 t}-1)$$

$$y(t) =  \dfrac{1}{3} c_2 e^{-6 t} (2 e^{3 t}+1)-\dfrac{1}{3} c_1 e^{-6 t} (e^{3 t}-1)$$

- Now, using all of the information below, direction fields, solutions, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, generate the phase portrait:

[image]

Comment: I am confused I should use the illustration graph you gave me to plots the lines?

Comment: No, you should do the work to derive the picture I gave you. Make sure you know how to arrive at this picture by hand using the instructor's instructions. In other words, re-generate this picture by hand and use all of the information you have. Regards

Comment: so this is the graph?

Comment: oh you mean by using all the information I have my graph should look something like the one you posted

Comment: Yes, this is the graph, but your instructor asked for specific things. That is precisely what I mean, you should arrive at a picture that looks like this, but the instructor also wanted things pointed out. Recall to upvote and/or accept answers that are helpful. Regards

Comment: Looks like a centipede with really! long legs!

Comment: You are right, those really creepy ones with 100 legs!

Answer (score 0):

Your eigenvectors are missing from your plot. Note that you already have them there in your solution. No need to scratch around for equations. Plot (2,1) and a constant multiple of, it say (-2,-1) and draw the line through the points. (Actually only the first point is needed since the eigenvector passes through (0,0)). Do the same for eigenvector represented by (-1,1). Throw on some arrow heads and you are done.  Greg L.